# Implement select_on_container_copy_construction() for STL Allocator

Tags: c++, c++11, allocator

I would like to provide a custom

```
select_on_container_copy_construction()
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/allocator_traits/select_on_container_copy_construction/

for my allocator.

I tried to add it directly to my allocator class like this:

```
T select_on_container_copy_construction( const T& a ) const {
  ...
}
```

but it is not called.

I tried to implement it as a type trait:

```
namespace std {
  template<class T>
  struct allocator_traits<static_allocator<T>> {
    typedef T value_type;
  };
}
```

but now I have to implement all other trait features as well.

Is there an easier way to just overwrite this function without having to provide a full `allocator_traits`?

Full code example can be found here:
https://onlinegdb.com/H1iJJIN1N

I tried various variants in adding static/const to the function.

Comment: `static allocator_type select_on_container_copy_construction (const allocator_type& alloc);` Yours is not static, and is const.

Comment: @sturcotte06 it is `static` in allocator traits, not in the allocator type itself

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki: Added a full code example. Thank you!

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki: Great! Thank you. I guess I was to focused on the documentation. I will accept it as an answer if you post it as such. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Allocator* named requirement [[allocator.requirements]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/allocator.requirements#tab:utilities.allocator.requirements) assumes the following calling syntax:

```
a.select_on_container_copy_construction()
```

and expects the return type to be the allocator type.

You declare an additional parameter (`const T& a`), which makes the above call ill-formed, forcing `std::allocator_traits` to fall back to the dafault implementation (returning the allocator instance) [[allocator.traits]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/allocator.traits#members-8):

> ```
> static Alloc select_on_container_copy_construction(const Alloc& rhs);
> ```
>
> *Returns:* `rhs.select_on_container_copy_construction()` if that expression is well-formed; otherwise, `rhs`.